# Do tables automatically enable for CDC in SQL Server when I enable it for Database?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, cdc, change-data-capture

I have created a database and created a table in it.
After that, I enabled CDC using `exec sys.sp_cdc_enable_db` for the whole database. When I checked, the database was enabled for CDC but the tables inside this database were not enabled for CDC automatically.

I know, we can enable CDC for tables one-by-one but I want to do that: When I enable CDC on any database, the tables inside it will automatically be enabled for CDC.

Am I missing something while enabling CDC for the database or should there be some other parameter in the stored procedure (above) itself?

Answer (score 1):

> After a database has been enabled for change data capture, members of
> the db_owner fixed database role can create a capture instance for
> individual source tables by using the stored procedure
> sys.sp_cdc_enable_table. To determine whether a source table has
> already been enabled for change data capture, examine the
> is_tracked_by_cdc column in the sys.tables catalog view.

[Change Data Capture - Enable For a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#enable-for-a-table)

Comment: we are enabling CDC on the database, so CDC is automatically enabled on all the tables of that database. why do we have to use the stored procedure for each table individually?

Comment: Because CDC is not automatically enabled on all the tables.